# How do you get gradle to access a string from a Java class in the project in my build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm fairly new to Gradle so excuse my ignorance: I have a class that has a static string containing the build version I want to set for the project. With gradle, I can't seem to access the project directly with just `MyClass.MyVersionString`.

What would be the easiest way to go about it? I can't seem to find a simple way of doing this.

Alternatively, if there was a way to access the Gradle version from my project, that too would help. The project needs access to the version, so I'd like a way to set it in one place and have everything else automagically update.

Thanks!

Comment: The typical solution is not to hardcode the version into a Java file, but to make the build tool generate a resource (properties) file containing the version information, which is then read by the Java code at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If building an **Android** project, you can do it the other way: use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` (or `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`), depending on what you need.

The `BuildConfig` class is automatically generated from the information in the AndroidManifest (and some other places, such as the flavor you're building).

Comment: I think I mistakenly added the android tag, but my project isn't an Android one. Do you know of an alternative? Thanks though!

Comment: @jonalmeida Uh sorry, no. I have only used Gradle with Android.

Comment: No problem, I've given you a +1 either way. Thank you!

Comment: @jonalmeida Heh thanks. I'll leave the answer here since it might be useful for Android developers who stumble upon it, I'll just edit it to make that clear. Sorry.